# Getting error in Jmeter point to point test plan

Tags: jmeter

I am getting following error

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]
```

what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Getting started user manual chapter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#libraries_activemq)

> [JMeter includes the JMS API jar](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#lets_start), but does not include a JMS client implementation. If you want to run JMS tests, you will need to download the appropriate jars from the JMS provider.

> You will need to add the jar [activemq-all-X.X.X.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all) to your classpath, e.g. by storing it in the lib/ directory.

> See [ActiveMQ initial configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/initial-configuration.html) page for details.

Don't forget to restart JMeter after placing the activemq-all.jar under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

More information: [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter)